# List not updating after inserting new value from another target SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to setup a action extension for my app. The action extension lets you save text to the main app thought a shared CoreData container.

The problem is that when I save text from the extension and return to the main app the updated data is not automatically loaded. The data added thought the extension does show up when I restart the app.

```
struct RecentsView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: nil, animation: .default)
    private var masterClips: FetchedResults<Clip>


   var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(masterClips, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item.text!)
                }
            }
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: "...The problem is that when I save text from the extension ..", well why don't you show us the code for the extension, together with enough code to replicate your problem.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Have you found a solution?